# ¿Cómo puedo crear una condición para los datos con los que un usuario llenara el arreglo?Java

Tags: java, array

Lo que quiero hacer es crear dos arreglos de tamaño 10, uno que se llene automáticamente  y otro que lo llene un usuario, pero para el segundo con la condición de que los números ingresados estén entre 101 y 150.

El primer arreglo funciono bien, pero el segundo al ingresarle el primer dato llena los 10 espacios del arreglo con ese numero.

Agradecería me pudieran ayudar con esto.

```
   static void vectores(){
 
    int[] A= new int[10];
    System.out.println ("\n");
    System.out.println("Los numeros dentro del vector A son: ");
    for (int posA = 0; posA < 10; posA++){
        A[posA] = (int)(Math.random()*99+1);
        System.out.print(A[posA] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println ("\n");
    System.out.println("Ingrese 10 numeros entre 101 y 150 para el vector B: ");
    
    int bb=101; 
    while( bb >= 101 && bb <= 150){
        
    Scanner leerB = new Scanner(System.in);
    bb = leerB.nextInt(); 
    
        int[] B= new int[10];
        for (int posB = 0; posB < 10; posB++){
            
            B[posB] = bb;
            
             System.out.print(B[posB] + " ");
        }   
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo repases los bucles. Para cada iteracion del for debes soliciatr la entrada al usuario y luego evaluar esa entrada. Anteriormente llenabas el arreglo con el mismo valor, pues el llenado se hacia en el for y tu pedias el dato fuera del for, por lo que el dato era el mismo en todo el ciclo for.

```
int bb=101;      
Scanner leerB = new Scanner(System.in); 
int[] B= new int[10];

   
for (int posB = 0; posB < 10; posB++){
        
       boolean flag = false;
       while(!flag){
          bb = leerB.nextInt();
          if( bb >= 101 && bb <= 150){
             B[posB] = bb;        
             flag = true;
             System.out.print(B[posB] + " ");
          }else{ 
             System.out.print("Introduzca un numero");
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: Tengo un problema, el for siempre se ejecutara 10 veces porque aunque el if no se cumpla igual se le sumara 1 a posB, entonces si el if no se cumple se le agrega un 0 al array. ¿Como puedo hacer para que si el if no se cumple se mantenga posB como esta (No se le agregue 1)? De forma que al array no se le agreguen 0s.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que solucione tu problema, suerte

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve pude resolverlo y llegue a esto.

```
     int bb;
    for(int posB= 0; posB < 10; posB++){

       boolean i=true;
            while(i==true){
                bb = leerB.nextInt();
                if (bb >= 101 && bb <= 150){
                    B[posB] = bb;
                    i=false;
                    System.out.println("El dato en la posicion " + posB + " es "+ B[posB]);
        }
                else {
                    System.out.println("El valor ingresado esta fuera de rango, vuelva a intentarlo.");
                }
        }
    }
```